# Need help using a ForLoop inside a ForLoop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am tasked with writing a program that displays the amount of asteriks that the user inputs, then squares it. So, if I were to input 6, the computer would display 36.

I am programming in **Java**.

This is what I should be getting:

```
Please enter the number of stars you would like(between 1 and 20):   4
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
```

Whenever I run the program, after it prints *Please enter the number of stars you would like(between 1 and 20):*, it displays the number I input...and nothing happens. BLANK.

Here is my code. I am not sure what I did wrong:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String star = "*";



    System.out.print("Please enter the number of stars you would like(between 1 and 20):\n>> ");
    int numStars = input.nextInt();

    for(int squared = numStars*numStars; squared < numStars+1; squared++)
    {
        for(int stop = 0; stop < numStars; stop++)
      {
            System.out.print(star+" ");
      }
        System.out.println(star+" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
```

Comment: why do you initialize `squared` to be `numStars*numStars`?

Comment: Well, because squared is equal to the number of stars I want displayed, squared.

Comment: `for(int squared = numStars*numStars; squared < numStars+1; squared++)` Read that like the computer would and see if it makes sense...

Comment: this is not working as sqaured is initialized with n * n , whereas it should state like, squared = 0; squared < (numstars * numstars) - 1; squared++)

Comment: Yeah you have an infinite loop there, and your problem is the first loop. You're over thinking your solution. Take a minute and write some pseudo code.

Comment: To expand, `numStars*numStars` will start out as larger than `numStars+1` for all numbers larger than 1.

Comment: The code to solve this should be simple. Print one line at a time, do it numStars times.

Comment: OK, I'm starting to see where I went wrong. Sorry for asking such a silly question but I am a noob at programming in Java (or any programming language), and the feedback I have received has helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop isn't entered because `squared < numStars+1` isn't true.

```
int numStars = 4;
String star = "*";
for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < numStars; j++) {
        if (j != 0)
            System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.print(star);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
```

Comment: That greatly helped. I know I should not be posting questions and waiting for an answer to be handed to me on a plate, but rather receiving feedback to help me understand what I did wrong, but I can see how your code makes sense in the math, whereas mine was faulty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `numStars` is 5.  Here's what the outer `for` loop does:

```
for(int squared = numStars*numStars; squared < numStars+1; squared++)
```

The first expression is an assignment that takes place at the beginning of the loop.  So the loop starts out by assigning `squares = 25`.

The second expression tells the program when to stop looping.  Or, actually, when to keep looping.  The way you've written the loop, it will continue as long as `squares < 6`.  As soon as `squares >= 6`, it stops.  And since `squares` starts out as 25, that means it stops immediately, and nothing inside the loop gets executed, ever.

You want to start by setting `squared` to either 0 or 1 at the beginning of the loop, instead of `numStars * numStars`.

Also, the variable name shouldn't be `squared`; that shows a misunderstanding of what the loop is for.  *Each time the program goes through the outer loop, it displays one row.*  That's what the outer loop's purpose is.  So calling the variable `rowNumber`, instead of `squared`, should make things clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I under stood what I did wrong and fixed the issue. The program now works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what you tried to do, but, one solution can be

```
for(int i = 0; i< numStars; i++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y< numStars; y++)
      {
        System.out.print(star+" ");
      }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing your statements in the first for loop.

squared is never less than numStars+1.

If numStars is 3, then squared will be 9 which is not less than 4. so its not executing your loop.

You can see this by adding a break point on the first for loop.

Also never assign a variable like that in a loop or if condition, its more readable to do the assignment outside.

Answer (score 0):

You want to draw a square with (using your example) 6 rows of 6 columns.

You want two loops, both counting up to the number of stars (forget about calculating squares)

The first loop is controlling rows, the second loops controls columns.

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < numStars; rows++) {
    for (int cols = 0; cols < numStars; cols++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using one `loop`

```
int input =4;
int square=input*input;
String star = "*";
for (int i = 0; i < square; i++) {
    if (i %input== 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(star + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer takes O(2n)

```
int numStars = 4;
String star = "*";
for (int i = 1; i < numStars; i++) {
    star += " *";
}
for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
    System.out.println(star);
}
```